# Internal server error when using xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium, phpunit

*I am using Selenium2 server and PHPUnit to run some basic unit tests, I am trying to click on the input field in this table:

```
<table id="items">               
            <tbody >
                <tr><td>
                    <input type="text" data-type="string" value="" class="text">
                 </td></tr>

            </tbody>  
</table>
```

And my xpath code looks like this:

```
$this->click("xpath=//table[@id='items']/input[@type='text']");
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```
/*PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Internal server error w
hile executing POST request at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/2ca03fc2-89d
b-4a6f-b209-340f11d65182/click. Response: NULL*/
```

I get this error every timne I try to execute the xpath method. Anyone know why that is?

Comment: Does it make a difference about which browser you use? Have you tried the equivalent CSS selector? Does that actually bring back many results? What version of Selenium?

Comment: I have only tried it in firefox, I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0, and the reason I haven't used css selector is because In can't figure out how to use it with php so I thought I would try the xpath approach.

Comment: Your XPath expression will not return any results, since `input` is not a direct child of `table`. Use this one instead with an extra **/** before **input**: `//table[@id='items']//input[@type='text']`.

Comment: I get the exact same error as before when adding the extra "/" to the code